# How can I draw an autoscaling D3.js graph that plots a mathematical function?

Tags: d3.js

I have [a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxxf/vbrf5y73/) that I made using JSXGraph, a graphing toolkit for mathematical functions. I'd like to port it to D3.js for personal edification, but I'm having  a hard time getting started.

The jsfiddle graphs the value of `-ke(-x/T) + k`, where x is an independent variable and the values of `k` and `t` come from sliders.

```
board.create('functiongraph',
  [
    // y = -k * e(-x/t) + k
    function(x) { return -k.Value()*Math.exp(-x/t.Value()) + k.Value(); },
    0
  ]
);
```

The three things I'm most stumped on:

- Actually drawing the graph and its axes - it's not clear to me which of the many parts of the D3 API I should be using, or what level of abstraction I should be operating at.
- Re-rendering the graph when a slider is changed, and making the graph aware of the value of the sliders.
- Zooming out the graph so that the asymptote defined by y = k is always visible and not within the top 15% of the graph. I do this now with:

  ```
  function getAestheticBoundingBox() {
    var kMag = k.Value();
    var tMag = t.Value();
    var safeMinimum = 10;
    var limit = Math.max(safeMinimum, 1.15 * Math.max(k.Value(), t.Value()));

    return [0, Math.ceil(limit), Math.ceil(limit), 0];
  }
  ```

What's the right way for me to tackle this problem?

Comment: Have you seen [this blog post](https://pavpanchekha.com/blog/plotting-d3.html)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Yes. Unfortunately, the link to the JS source is broken (uses a `file://` url), the code doesn't work as described in the post, and the `Chart` constructor isn't really raw D3, which is what I'd like to use.

Comment: Ok, well the basic idea is to generate is to sample the function for the `x` values covered and then use e.g. a line generator to connect the points. Apart from that, it's pretty much standard D3 that you should be able to find lots of tutorials/examples for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [threw this example together really quick](http://plnkr.co/edit/lVv0SU8wYVuFc7al7WgD?p=preview), so don't ding me on the code quality.  But it should give you a good starting point for how you'd do something like this in `d3`.  I implemented everything in straight `d3`, even the [sliders](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6452972).

As @LarKotthoff says, the key is that you have to loop your function and build your data:

```
// define your function
var func = function(x) {
  return -sliders.k() * Math.exp(-x / sliders.t()) + sliders.k();
},
// your step for looping function
step = 0.01;

drawPlot();

function drawPlot() {

  // avoid first callback before both sliders are created
  if (!sliders.k ||
      !sliders.t) return;

  // set your limits
  var kMag = sliders.k();
  var tMag = sliders.t();
  var safeMinimum = 10;
  var limit = Math.max(safeMinimum, 1.15 * Math.max(kMag, tMag));

  // generate your data
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < limit; i += step) {
    data.push({
      x: i,
      y: func(i)
    })
  }

  // set our axis limits
  y.domain(
    [0, Math.ceil(limit)]
  );
  x.domain(
    [0, Math.ceil(limit)]
  );

  // redraw axis
  svg.selectAll("g.y.axis").call(yAxis);
  svg.selectAll("g.x.axis").call(xAxis);

  // redraw line
  svg.select('.myLine')
    .attr('d', lineFunc(data))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I have a question: are all D3 graphs manually rendered this way? I ask because this only seems to work because the slope is not "too big". If the value of the function changes rapidly, it seems like one would want to sample more frequently, rather than having a constant sampling interval. Is there an established way to have D3 automatically scale the frequency, or is constant-sampling just the way everybody does it?

Comment: @JohnFeminella, that's a good question and I don't have an answer.  I haven't really seen many examples of using d3 for continuous function plotting.  Most all the examples are over discrete data.  There does exist  options for [interpolation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_interpolate) but I know that's not quite what you are asking.  Looking into the guts of the library you link to the sampling seems to happen [here](https://github.com/jsxgraph/jsxgraph/blob/e235c94e566529eb299dbedef4ed77d1b6844ff5/src/base/curve.js#L420).

Comment: @JohnFeminella, talking this over with a couple fellow nerds at work, it seems the most trivial sample rate calculation would be `(xRange.max - xRange.min) / (number of pixels [width] of x axis)`...

Comment: Hm, yeah -- that definitely makes sense. That would require resampling on every re-render, right?

Comment: @JohnFeminella, yes, I don't see a way around that.