# How to draw an ellipsis as position reference in Google Scatter Chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

How can I draw shapes like the ellipsis showed in the following image in Google Charts?

The data that I have to plot is better represented by the Scatter Chart, but I don't see how I could draw the lines and ellipsis knowing their equation.

[image: chart with ellipsis]

Comment: add a row for each point along the ellipsis to the data table used to draw the chart. the more points, the more it will look like an ellipsis...

Comment: I thought about something similar to this, but with this approach points of the ellipsis would react to mouse hovers, what's not the goal.

Comment: It seems to be possible using D3 based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755411/how-can-i-draw-an-autoscaling-d3-js-graph-that-plots-a-mathematical-function . But would be very nice to keep the solution in Google Charts.

Comment: you can turn off interactivity --> `enableInteractivity: false`

Comment: It's seems to be a good approach, I might go for it because a lack of better options. The problem that I already can see with this is that the `enableInteractivity` options is by chart, so the real data points would lose mouse hover as well.

Comment: you can disable by series, using the `series` option, so you could add another column / series with a copy of the real data points.